# Not-so-[random] tag for [dice]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I created the [dice](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dice) tag this morning. At over 60 candidate questions, it was time. Here is the [list of candidate questions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=Is%3Aq+Dice+-%5Bdice%5D+closed%3Ano).

When adding the tag, please be sure to make all appropriate edits. Of special note, [random](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random) will probably be appropriate on many of these. Add it too, as necessary.

This is a significant number of questions to bump, so please work on small batches as not to flood the main page.

Comment: Should this tag apply to dices exclusively or rather all kinds of game of chance simulation, such as tossing coins, spinning wheels or even mixing cards?  Maybe the tag description could say something about this?

Comment: I had only thought of the dice use case, as that's what I've seen most of, but any of those things could be thought of as a special type of die. A coin, for instance, could be modeled as a two-sided die. Why don't you go ahead and submit an edit on the tag wiki @5gon12eder?

Comment: Alright, I've submitted [an edit suggestion](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/37481).  It seems a rather dramatic change to me but let's see what the fellow reviewers will have to say about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've completed the retag and 5gon2eder created a tag wiki.